# Order type of a set that is ordered but not well-ordered

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

I looking at ordered sets in the Kolmogorov (Introductory Read Analysis) book.

Section 3.5 Definition 2 says

> the order type of a well ordered set is called an ordinal number. If the set is infinite, the ordinal is transfinite

So the set of positive integers $\{1,2,...,k,..\}$ arranged in increasing order is well ordered with the order type $\omega$.

The set $\{..., -k,.., -2, -1\}$ is ordered but not well-ordered. But this set is isomorphic to the set of positive integers - map each element to its negative.

So if order type is something shared by all isomorphic sets (Section 3.3), why can the set of negative integers (a set that is ordered but not well ordered and is isomorphic to a well ordered set) not have an order type?

More broadly, if a set is ordered but not well ordered, but is isomorphic to a well ordered set, why should it not have an order type?

Comment: $(\Bbb Z_-,\le)$ is not order-isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_+,\le)$, because there is no strictly increasing bijective map between them. $(\Bbb Z_-,\ge)$ would be.

Comment: You should always assume the two "isomorphic objects" are meant to be isomorphic *as something* (formally, as objects of some [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics))). Sometimes the category is obvious from context (for instance, when one says that two groups are isomorphic they usually mean that they are isomorphic as groups) but it's actually rather uncommon - even obscure, in my opinion - to call isomorphic two sets that are in bijection with one another: you would say that they have the same cardinality, or that they are equinumerous.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that clarification. Very helpful. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90923/isomorphism-of-sets

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Actually, even the Kolmogorov book says that (Sec. 3.2) - *an isomorphism between $M$ and $M'$ is a bijection such that $f(a) \leq f(b)$ iff $a \leq b$ (where $a, b \in M$)*. Going by this, the mapping of an integer to its negative actually isn't an order preserving mapping. So is it then **wrong** to call it an isomorphism?? Now I'm confused.

Comment: @Ahron Any bijection from $(\Bbb Z_+,\le)$ to $ (\Bbb Z_-,\le)$ can't be an isomorphism. However  $f:   (\Bbb Z_+,\le)\to 
  (\Bbb Z_-,\ge)$  defined by $f(z) =-z$ is an order isomorphism.

Comment: @Ahron Yes, bar what Lost in Space said, which was one of my points. For the record, the definition you say is correct and it's more accurate than mine because it works for all orders (i.e. the partial orders). Mine is equivalent to that one for total orders: specifically, a map $f:(X,\le)\to (Y,\preceq)$ between total orders is an order isomorphism if and only if it is strictly increasing and bijective, if and only if it is strictly increasing and there is some strcitly increasing function $g:(Y,\preceq)\to (X,\le)$ such that $f\circ g=id_Y$ and $g\circ f=id_X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, there are some problems with the question details, involving misunderstanding of a bijection as an isomorphism.

The crux of the question was that if a well-ordered set $A$ has an order type, and the set $A$ has a bijection with another set $B$, then $B$ should also have an order type.

This is a somewhat similar confusion as raised [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3992821/does-bijectivity-imply-the-same-order-type).

The answer is in [the Mathworld article on this topic:](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderType.html)

> In general, if $\alpha$ is any order type, then $^*\alpha$ is the same type ordered backwards (Dauben 1990, p. 153).

The order type of the set $Z_-$ is $^*\omega$ or $\omega^*$.

Bijectivity implies the same cardinality. Not the same order type. $Z_-$ is bijective to $Z_+$, so they are [*equipotent* or *equipollent*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Equipollent.html), so their cardinalities are the same.

> Tarski (1924) proposed to instead define a cardinal number by stating that every set A is associated with a cardinal number |A|, and two sets A and B have the same [cardinal number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CardinalNumber.html) iff they are equipollent

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ (\Bbb Z_+,\le)$ and $(\Bbb Z_-,\le)$ are order isomorphic.

Then $\exists f:\Bbb{Z}_+ \to \Bbb{Z}_-$ such that

1. $f$ is binjective.
2. $f$ preserve order i.e $a\le b$ implies $f(a) \le f(b) $

Since $|\Bbb{Z}_+|=\aleph_0=| \Bbb{Z}_-|$ , hence there is a bijection between $\Bbb{Z}_+ $ and $\Bbb{Z}_-$.

Claim: No bijection $f: \Bbb{Z}_+ \to \Bbb{Z}_-$ is not order preserving.

Proof: Assume the contrary.

Let $f(1) =u$

Then $\forall x\in \Bbb{Z}_+  \space , 1\le x$ implies  $u=f(1) \le f(x) $

i.e $u\le y\space , \forall y\in \Bbb{Z}_-$ implies $u$ is the least element which is a contradiction because $\Bbb{Z}_-$ in it's usual ordering has no least element (given any $u\in \Bbb{Z}_-  $ , $u-1<u$ ).

Note: Order isomorphism between two poset maps least element to least element.

Conclusion: $(\Bbb{Z}_+, \le) $ and $( \Bbb{Z}_-, \le) $ is not order isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications about order isomorphism. I took the time to figure it out and came up with an answer that gets to the crux of my problem.